# Cross compile from CentOS 7 to Raspberry Pi 2B - can't get LIBC and system include headers to work together

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, centos, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a hello world C program on a CentOS 7 64-bit machine to the Raspberry Pi 2B 32-bit target machine.

I downloaded the buster cross compiler `cross-gcc-8.3.0-pi_2-3.tar.gz`

My hello world C file is the standard hello world program that we all use.

When I inch up on my compile first just trying to compile

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o helloworld.exe helloworld.c
```

gives me:

```
/home/<redacted>/repos/pi-2-compiler/cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/<redacted>/repos/pi-2-compiler/cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The libc version is different on my CentOS machine from the target.  The `libc.so.6` file is in the cross compile path, so when I use the `--sysroot` option, I get over the libc problem, but get an inability to find the `stdio.h` file.

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o helloworld.exe helloworld.c --sysroot=/home/<redacted>/repos/pi-2-compiler/cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib
helloworld.c:1:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The stdio.h file is in the cross compile path, but I can't determine way to add that path to the `gcc` command without destroying my link to the libc world.  I tried -I, -isystem, .... but when I do that, I get the original GLIBC error

I am not inventing the wheel here, so there must be something I am missing.  I am just getting into this cross compiling thing, and need help to build up my knowledge.  I read may sites, but haven't quite found the answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you'll need `--sysroot`. But, you may need a `-I` for the arm versions of the `.h` files. On my cross devel system for arm (ubuntu), I have a `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu` directory that has subdirs of `bin`, `include`, and `lib` So, for me [and it's been a while], I think I'd need `-I/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include`. Your paths are a bit more complex, but I'd start with `-I/home/<redacted>/repos/pi-2-compiler/cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/include`. You can always do: `find /home/<redacted>/repos/pi-2-compiler/cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1 -type f -name include` or similar. In dirs it finds, look for `stdio.h`

Comment: If you have root/admin access to your system, you could _install_ the compilers, etc. They might show up in `/usr/local/something`. Then, your build makefiles/scripts could be simplified and would get rid of the `/home/redacted` dependency. The result would be reusable by other [non-redacted] users. Correction on the `find` command: `-type d` (oops).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I am behind a wall that does not let me install anything, although I do have admin rights on the CentOS box.

When I use the --sysroot to get to the libc.so.6 file, It is overridden if I use the -I switch to point to the include directory that has the stdio.h file.  

I don't know how to manipulate where the "ld" program looks for the libc.so.6 so I can use the -I for the include headers.

Comment: My memory is still hazy ;-) But, I just started looking through scripts/config on my cross-devel system. Whatever you point `--sysroot` to, it should be the final hierarchy (i.e. From `/` on the _target_ system). So, under [one of] my `--sysroot=`, I have subdirs: `etc lib sbin usr/bin usr/include usr/lib usr/libexec usr/sbin usr/share` And, (e.g.) `stdio.h` is `/path_to_my_sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h` So, what does _your_ `sysroot` top directory look like?

Comment: Here are the locations of the bits;
$ find . -name "libc.so.6"
./cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/libc.so.6

$ find . -name "stdio.h"
./cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
./cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/8.3.0/tr1/stdio.h
./cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/stdio.h
./cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include/bits/stdio.h

To get the libc to work, I have to use a sysroot that goes ...\libc\lib
This takes me beyond the ...\libc\usr\include where stdio.h file is

Comment: It seems like I should be able to stop at the ...\libc
that way the libc.so.6 would be in ...\libc\lib
and the stdio.h would be in ...\libc\usr\include

Comment: I see that the libc.so.6 is a symbolic link to another libc.so.  I am looking to move those files up a directory so I can set my --sysroot to stop at libc.

Comment: Where did you download your tar file from? Also, if you have admin rights on the CentOS box, I think you _can_ install things. From the results of your `find`, they don't match up with what I'm used to. Also, if you're going to create an RPi SD-card, you'll need admin rights because the sysroot area needs correct uid/gid that must match the target. You have to create an exact FS hierarchy (with uids/permissions) that you then put onto a disk image file, burn that to the SD card, put the card into the RPi.

Comment: The CentOS box is not connected to internet.  There is a repository of packages that I can pick from if I know the name.  The packages with arm-linux in their name are;
binutils-arm-linux-gnu.x86_64
gcc-arm-linux-gnu.x86_64
gcc-c++-arm-linux-gnu.x86_64
My target is 32-bit so I don't know if these will work as "installed" compilers.

The tar file I downloaded was from;
https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20GCC%20Cross-Compiler%20Toolchains/Buster/GCC%208.3.0/Raspberry%20Pi%202%2C%203/

Comment: Craig - your comment about where did I get my tar file from got me thinking.  I downloaded the 10.2.0 version of the cross compiler for buster from the website, and it worked fine.  Thank you for questioning my starting point and helping to reveal where I was going off the rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a total solution, but some explanation ...

The TL;DR: Unfortunately, we don't have all the files we need.

---

I downloaded and extracted the tar file from the link you provided.

It creates a subdirectory: `cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1`

Under that directory, we have subdirectories. Of note [some] are:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf
bin
lib
```

To use a given cross-development utility (e.g. `ld` but similar for `gcc`, `ar`, etc.) they are located:

```
./bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld
```

These files are *identical*. Also, [again] they are `x86_64`
binaries that *cross* build for arm.

So, to be able to use the cross build there are two methods:

1. Set the `PATH` variable: `export PATH=/home/redacted/cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/arm-linux-gnueabihf`. Then, if we type the command `ld <something>`, we are *not* using the native x86_64 version but the x86_64 to arm cross version.
2. Instead of using `ld`, we can use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld`. Here, in our `Makefile`, we'd do something like: `LD = arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld` at the top. This works *if* we install the cross compiler so that the package `bin` is extracted into a standard `bin` directory (such as `/usr/local/bin`
3. Otherwise, we'd need to do: `export PATH=/home/redacted/cross-pi-gcc-8.3.0-1/bin` and setting `LD` as above.

Either way, we can now cross-build for arm ... Sort of ...

Under the `lib` directory, we have `libcc1*` files. These are build for x86_64.

---

The problem is that we do *not* have an `aarch64/arm` version of a library. So, if we do:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o hello hello.c
```

There is *no* `aarch64` (arm) version of (e.g.) `libc`.

In other words, the package you downloaded has [just] the cross-compiler but no *target* system libraries.

In other words, we'd need to add `--sysroot=/path_to_sysroot` to the `gcc` command.

But, we do *not* have the `sysroot` files.

With `--sysroot`, we'd expect to find:

```
/path_to_sysroot/bin/ls
/path_to_sysroot/lib/libc*
```

And, the `ls` would be the `aarch64/arm` binary and the `libc` would have the library code compiled for `aarch64/arm`

---

So, to remedy this, we have to find and download suitable packages that *do* have pre-built `aarch64/arm` binaries and have `--sysroot=` point to the top directory for these.

Just to recap ... The `sysroot` directory should have the exact file hierarchy that the *target* system (e.g. the RPi) will have starting from its root `/` directory.

---

Again, what you have is *just* the cross-compiler. But, *no* target libraries or binaries (e.g. `ls`, `vim`, etc.)

You may want to consider a more full featured, one stop approach, such as `linaro`:

- https://www.linaro.org/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linaro

Comment: Thank you for your diligence.  See my note on moving onto the 10... version from the website, with that one, no --sysroot or anything was needed.  I will accept this one as an answer so you get credit.  Thanks again.